# @Html.DropDownListFor onchange is not calling the mentioned Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, onchange, html.dropdownlistfor, actionresult

I am trying to call a controller method "**GetTasksList**" onchange of dropdown value in view. However onchange of dropdown, the "Edit" method of Controller is being called and submitting the form to database. This is undesirable because I am trying to fetch a list of tasks from the database based on the dropdownvalue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY5LO.png)

View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AuditDecision, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListofAuditDecision, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control input-10", id = "AuditStatus", onchange = "testing();", @style = "width: 300px;" })

<script>
  function testing() {
        alert("in testing");
        document.forms[0].action = 'GetAuditTasksList';
       // window.location.href = 'GetAuditTasksList';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

The control goes to below method

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Audit audit)
        {
 //submitting to database
}
```

instead of

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetAuditTasksList(Audit audit)
        {
}
```

Comment: This seems to work when I create a new form (http://localhost:64577/Audit/Create) ,save it and then immediately edit it http://localhost:64577/Audit/Edit. However when I edit it later on, the URL is http://localhost:64577/Audit/Edit/5dcdd8c1d7078b1afd0f28, where “5dcdd8c1d7078b1afd0f28” is the unique identifier, control goes to Edit method and submits the form on dropdown value change and doesn’t fetch the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a helper method to generate the correct action uri for the form. This way you can explicitly pass any required parameters and are protected from any future changes to your routing rules. eg;

```
    document.forms[0].action = '@Url.Action("GetAuditTasksList", ... )';
```